# Binomial distribution wording

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution

I get confused when the question says "At least, more than, less than, at most", for example, "On average at all the schools in this country 30% of students do not like any sports: 10 of the students from this country are chosen at random, find the probability that at least 3 of these students do not like any sports"

Am I supposed to do P(0) + P(1) + P(2) + P(3) or is it P(0) + P(1) + P(2)

Comment: "At least 3" means 3 or more. The opposite of this is 2 or less, so you want $1-(P(0)+P(1)+P(2))$.

Comment: Got it, so what about more than less than or at most

Comment: "Less than 3" means $X < 3,$ so $P(X < 3) = P(0)+P(1)+P(2).$ "At most 3" means $X\le 3.$